# how to convert base64 code to image in magento 2

Tags: api, base64, magento-2.0

i am creating magento api that receives the base64 encoded image code .
from api side i receive the that string.now i have to convert that image code and save into required destination.
how to achieve this in magento 2.can i get that image name from that encoded image.please help with this.
I have a code to convert base 64 to image in php. But i want know whether same code works in magento evnvironment

```
function base64_to_jpeg( $base64_string, $output_file ) {
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, "wb" ); 
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $base64_string) ); 
    fclose( $ifp ); 
    return( $output_file ); 
}

$image = base64_to_jpeg( $my_base64_string, 'tmp.jpg' );
```

Answer (score 1):

inject these in your constructor:

```
 \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface $MediaGalleryEntry,
 \Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface $imageContentInterface,
```

During product creation I do something like this:

```
 $mediaGalleryEntry = $this->_mediaGalleryEntry;
 $mediaGalleryEntry->setLabel($name);
 $mediaGalleryEntry->setTypes(array("image","small_image","thumbnail"));
 $mediaGalleryEntry->setStoreIds($storeIds);
 $mediaGalleryEntry->setMediaType('image');
 $mediaGalleryEntry->setPosition(0);      

 $imageContent = $this->_imageContentInterface;                  
 $imageContent->setName($name);
 $imageContent->setType($imageType);
 $imageContent->setBase64EncodedData($imageData);
 $mediaGalleryEntry->SetContent($imageContent);

 $product->setMediaGalleryEntries(array($mediaGalleryEntry));
```